# Trying to disable button if text hasn’t being input and one of three check box hasn’t been checked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable a button that requires both an input of text being typed and one of three checkboxes being checked. The text is a user name and the checkbox is a difficulty of either easy, medium, or hard. Currently, my function only works if one of the requirements is met. So if the text has been inputted the button is enabled and the same with the checkboxes.

```js
startButton.addEventListener('click', startQuiz);

function disableButton() {
  if (document.getElementById("username").value === "") {
    document.getElementById("start-btn").disabled = true;
  }

  if (document.getElementsByName("difficulty").checked) {
    document.getElementById("start-btn").disabled = true;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("start-btn").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
 

<div>
<label for="username">Enter your Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeyup="disableButton()" placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>
<div id="difficulty" class="center">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff" onclick="disableButton()">
    <label for="easy-diff">Easy</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff" onclick="disableButton()">
    <label for="medium-diff">Medium</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff" onclick="disableButton()">
    <label for="hard-diff">Hard</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="start-btn" type="submit" class="btn"  disabled>Start</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` doesn’t return Elements. Remove all `onclick` attributes. This is a good use case for [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation). If all `<input>`s are in a `<form id="theForm">`, just use `document.getElementById("theForm").addEventListener("input", () => document.getElementById("start-btn").disabled = document.querySelector("#theForm [name='difficulty']:checked") && document.getElementById("username").value);`.

Comment: Even better: use the [`required`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute.

Comment: So I should put all the inputs and the button in a <form>  and add required to each of the checkbox inputs, the username input, and use the code that you added? or not use the code?

Comment: The `required` attribute helps perform form validation on submit. The event listener disables the submit button, but not submitting the form. You can use both approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time the value changed, check both input

```js
let diffChecked = false;
let startButton = document.querySelector('#start-btn');
let username = document.querySelector('#username');
let difficulty = document.querySelectorAll('[name="difficulty"]');

username.addEventListener('input', function() {
  validateInput();
})

difficulty.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    diffChecked = true;
    validateInput();
  })
})

function validateInput() {
  if (username.value && diffChecked) {
    startButton.disabled = false;
  } else {
    startButton.disabled = true
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="username">Enter your Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>
<div id="difficulty" class="center">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff">
    <label for="easy-diff">Easy</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff">
    <label for="medium-diff">Medium</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff">
    <label for="hard-diff">Hard</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="start-btn" type="submit" class="btn" disabled>Start</button>
```

Comment: Would there be a way to add to the username.addEventListener('input', function() {
  validateInput(); to stop whitespace being inputed or would that be a entirely different function?

Comment: @Huey: change `username.value` to `username.value.trim().length`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `div` you must use the Semantic HTML `form`, that will do the job for you without even writing javascript code.

```
<form id="difficulty" class="center">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff" required>
    <label for="easy-diff">Easy</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff" required>
    <label for="medium-diff">Medium</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff" required>
    <label for="hard-diff">Hard</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Inside a `form` tag, the submit button only works with all required inputs does not have an undefined value.

And you may call your function `startQuiz` as an action, if you want.
The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted.

```
<form id="difficulty" class="center" action="startQuiz()">
```